# Spell checker in iPhone application

Tags: ios, ios4

I am working on messaging app,so for sending message i have take textField for taking input.I wanted to implement spell check with this i mean whenever user is entering any text ,it should be checking the spelling either it's correct or wrong?
If you have any idea please share with me orgive me some pointer.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Select the textfield in which you are entering your text in interface builder. Open the inspector window,switch to the attributes tab, then set the value of correction to yes in textinput traits.